# MEX endpoint for WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to set up an STS test scenario with an STS service, a webservices and a client. The Secure Token Service is from the Identity Server of WSO2 and runs at endpoint

```
https://[domain]:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts/
```

the webservice and client are written in java with Netbeans. I run the client and get:

```
 WST0017:Could not obtain STS metadata. MEX call to STS https://[domain]:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts/mex failed.
```

What is the endpoint of the MEX service of the Secure Token Service in WSO2?

Answer (score 1):

MEX is a protocol that is supposed to help automatically identify the details of the web-service being called. These non-obvious errors tend to happen when the calling library needs the WSDL but is provided with the URL to the endpoint instead. As a result it tries to use MEX to find the WSDL, but since the server does not implement MEX this fails and returns these non-obvious errors.

In practice the fix is almost always to provide the URL to the WSDL (which contains the details of the end point URL) rather than directly to the endpoint. I don't know enough about WSO2, but commonly the WSDL is exposed by appending ?wsdl or similar to the end point URL.